# A nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object

Tags: c++, oop

I simplified my more complex code to this simple example which gives the same error:

```
class MyClass {

    int i;

public:

    void someFunction() {

        struct MyStruct {

            void someOtherFuction() {
                i++;
            }

        };

        MyStruct mystruct;
        mystruct.someOtherFuction();
    }

};
```

With the corresponding main function:

```
#include "MyClass.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    MyClass myClass;

    myClass.someFunction();
}
```

The error being:

```
A nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object
```

So I modified `int i;` to be `static int i;` but then I got this other error:

```
unresolved external symbol "private: static int MyClass::i"
```

Can someone please tell me what is the way to go around this?

Comment: C++ is not java. `MyStruct` is not part of `MyClass`  in any way, and so does not have an `i` it can use.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass in a reference to the member variable `i` to the helper struct’s member function.

```
class MyClass {
    int i = 0;

public:
    void someFunction() {
        struct MyStruct {
            void someOtherFuction(int& ii) {
                ii++;
            }   
        };  

        MyStruct mystruct;
        mystruct.someOtherFuction(i);
    }   
};

int main() {
    MyClass myClass;
    myClass.someFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

```
class MyClass {

    int i;

public:

    void someFunction() {

        struct MyStruct {

            int* iPtr;

            MyStruct(int* iPtr) {
                this->iPtr = iPtr;
            }

            void someOtherFuction() {
                *iPtr++;
            }

        };

        MyStruct mystruct(&i);
        mystruct.someOtherFuction();
    }

};
```